# how to play a static video in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am working with react-native. when I used the package `react-native-video`, My packager gets stuck. Is there is any alternative way for this. when I go through the documentation, I saw Image component can support the video. Is that possible?

Comment: have you created app via Expo or React-native CLI ?

Comment: yes. I used create-react-native-app command as specified in react-native documentation.

Comment: Okay then try with Video of Expo

Comment: can you please help me with a sample code? I face similiar issues with react-native-model too.

Comment: Sure , can you share the snippet of what your trying? By the way what was the issues with react-native-modal?

Comment: I am not quit sure about it. beacouse when ever  installed any new packages. stucked in starting packager

Comment: am sorry. I didn't get you